# Null Pointer Exception runiing AWS Lambda With Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aws-lambda, autowired

I'm creating a sample of web service using Spring boot. When I run it in the localhost and test with Postman, it works fine. But when I deploy the application on AWS Lambda, it throws a nullpointerException.

When I was testing locally and on AWS Lambda this was working fine, until I started using @autowired

[This is the project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUKcV.png)

The endpont or handle request is in the class LoginController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="api/auth/v1")
public class LoginController {

   @Autowired
   IClientCredentialService _clientCredentialService;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
   public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody ClientCredential clientCredential){

    //For testing from Postman and AWS, clientCredential is not null.

    if(clientCredential == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<VOGenericResponse>(new VOGenericResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.name()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    
    if(clientCredential.getClientId() == null || clientCredential.getClientId().equals("")) {
        return new ResponseEntity<VOGenericResponse>(new VOGenericResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.name()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    
    if(clientCredential.getClientSecret() == null || clientCredential.getClientSecret().equals("")) {
        return new ResponseEntity<VOGenericResponse>(new VOGenericResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.name()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    
    else {
        
        ClientCredential client = _clientCredentialService.findClientCredential(clientCredential.getClientId(), clientCredential.getClientSecret());
        
        //TODO Obtener token aquí
        
        Token token = new Token();
        token.setCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        token.setDescription(HttpStatus.OK.name());
        
        //Temp
        token.setAccessToken("123");
        token.setCreatedDate("Hoy");
        token.setUpdatedDate("Hoy");
        token.setExpiresIn("Mañana");
        token.setStartIn("Hoy");
        token.setTokenId("321");
        token.setTokenType("bearer");
        token.setUpdatedDate("hoy");
        
        return new ResponseEntity<Token>(token, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The interface IClientCredentialService, escencially has a method, and the class ClientCredentialServiceImpl, implements that interface:

```
@Service("clientCredentialService")
@Transactional
public class ClientCredentialServiceImpl implements IClientCredentialService{

    @Override
    public ClientCredential findClientCredential(String clientId, String clientSecret) {
    
        return new ClientCredential();
    }
}
```

This is the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AwsLambdaSurveyAuthServerLoginV1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
     SpringApplication.run(AwsLambdaSurveyAuthServerLoginV1Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the classes ClientCredential and Token, has a constructor and some getters and setters.

When I run it from postman, It works fine, I get a 200 http response:

```
{
"code": 200,
"description": "OK",
"tokenId": "321",
"accessToken": "123",
"tokenType": "bearer",
"expiresIn": "Mañana",
"startIn": "Hoy",
"createdDate": "Hoy",
"updatedDate": "hoy"
}
```

but, when I run It from AWS Lambda y get this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "stackTrace": [
   "com.gns.survey.authserver.login.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:47)",
  "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
  "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
  "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
  "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
 ]
}
```

Anyone know what the error is? I really appreciate your help.

/Edit: Method with null validation

Comment: what's on the line 47 on LoginController?

Comment: `ClientCredential client = _clientCredentialService.findClientCredential(clientCredential.getClientId(), clientCredential.getClientSecret());` , here either _clientCredentialService or clientCredential can be NULL. Please verify which one of these field is null first.

Comment: I think your project structure has issues, can you post the main java class and any customisation you did?

Comment: @gtiwari333, thanks for your response. "clientCredential" is not null, I'm sending it from Postman or AWS Lambda test.

Comment: Since the same code is working locally, I don't think the autowiring/component scan is a problem. So, I don't think _clientCredentialService is null here. So, I still think the clientCredential might be null. Which is a valid hypothesis because you are running it as  the lambda function and some configuration is not passing the body

Comment: Please add if/else null check at the beginning of login method to find out what's null. then deal with that accordingly

Comment: The line throwing exception can have error at 2 places, either the repo object is null or request body but running on local argument is valid for both, so it would be better OP add more info to the question.

Comment: An `@Autowired` field cannot be `null`. If spring cannot satisfy an `@Autowired` field the application won't start and will fail with an `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`. So it isn't the field that is `null` but the content that is coming in. That is given that the code you shown here is also the code that you are actually using and not some dumbed down version.